# How do I read first line from a text file validate and then read the rest of the file in to an array?

Tags: php

I have a problem with the reading and validating some files(.txt). What I am trying to do is to read the first line from the text which has 4 columns:  a module name, a title name, a teacher name and a date. I need to take this first line to convert into a string and validate each column. After validation to continue to read the file on the next line which it has 2 columns one for id and one for marks. I need to take the second line as well and validate the id and the marks.

The text files are in this format. Some of them are missing the date or the name.

```
DT1617T1, Problem Solving for Programming , Gordon MacIntyre  , 20/05/2016
12345678, 56
34567822, 67
12324654, 98
234769O1, 45
12563792, 49
74537299, 7I
99834511, 50
77625489, 56
55274559, 63
22009643, 71
72578129, 51
```

I got stuck and I don't know how to read the first line validate and then read the rest from second line. I have to do all this in a loop to read multiple files. I managed to read and validate the first line appart of the date cause I don't know how to do that as well. But now I need to start reading from the second line without the first line.
This is one of my projects for school I just started as a programmer and if anyone can help me, please.

```
<?php 
function sorting(){
$dataFolder = 'data';
// checking if directory with the name 'data' exists
     if(is_dir($dataFolder)){  
          $textFiles = glob("$dataFolder/*.txt"); //extracting the files with the   extension .txt


              $i=0;//counter for the files array;
              $errorCount=0;//counting error in the first line of text;
              //sorting the .txt files and extracting the first line from file
              foreach($textFiles as $files){ //looping trought the folder and extracting all the files with extension .txt
                 $codeLines = fopen($files, "r");//opening the files

                 $fileContets=file_get_contents($files);//getting all content of the file for validation
                 $fLine=fgets($codeLines) ;//reading the files
                 $fLine=explode("," , $fLine);//storring the first line of text as an array
                 fclose($codeLines);//closing the file
                   //validation function
                  if(filesize($files) == 0 or $fileContets == "" ){ echo "<p>Ups the file is empty</p>";}

                     $moduleCode =  $fLine[0]; //first item in the array $fLine
                     $moduleTitle = $fLine[1]; //second item in the array $fLine
                     $tutorName =   $fLine[2]; //third item in the array $fLine
                     $dateMarking = $fLine[3]; //forth item in the array $fLine

                  $errorLog="<p>Module Code: $moduleCode- ERROR Module code is incorect</p>"; //error code
                  $x = "<p>Module Code: $moduleCode </p>";// no error


                  echo "<p>File name: $textFiles[$i]  </p>"; // echo the file name that is currently itterate

                  $i++;


                  if (!preg_match('/^(PP|P1|DT)[\d]{4}T[123]/' , $moduleCode)) {
                       $errorCount++;                       
                       echo $errorLog; }
                  else  
                        {echo " <p>Module Code: $moduleCode </p>" ; }

                  if($moduleTitle == "")
                        {echo "<p>Title:  ERROR -  Title is missig </p>"; $errorCount++;}
                  else
                        {echo "<p>Title: $moduleTitle </p>"; }

                  if($tutorName == "")
                        {echo "<p>Tutor Name: ERROR - Tutor name is missing </p>"; $errorCount++;}
                  else 
                        {echo "<p>Tutor Name: $tutorName</p>";}


                      $handle = fopen($files  , 'r');
                              while (!feof($handle)) {
                        $name = fgets($handle, 1024);
                         echo '<p>' . $name . '</p>'; }


                  }

                        echo"<p>Numbers of errors on file is : `enter code here`$errorCount</p>";


                    }

                  }

     sorting();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to open the file, read the first line - validate, if that is valid then read each line after till end of file and validate these lines.  Also use [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read the file, it gives you an array of the fields in the file without having to use `explode()`.

You may be better off with more of a structure like...

```
          foreach($textFiles as $files){ //looping trought the folder and extracting all the files with extension .txt
             $codeLines = fopen($files, "r");//opening the files

             $fLine=fgetcsv($codeLines) ;//reading the files

             // Validate the 1st line

             if ( !$valid ) {
                 fclose ( $codeLines );
                 continue;    // Skip rest of read
             }

             while ( !feof($codeLines) ) {  // Loop to end of file
                 $fLine = fgetcsv($codeLines) ;

                 // Validate the rest of the lines

             }
             fclose ( $codeLines );   // When finished close the file
```